# For the Java BigInteger Class, is there a way to define an if-statement with multiple conditions, seperated by logical operators?

Tags: java, if-statement, biginteger

Here is a method in Java which will be producing an ArrayList containing the first 100,000,000th fibonacci numbers, such that none of these fibonacci numbers are divisible by any smaller square number.

As a result, the **BigInteger** Java class is being implemented to handle numbers of an exceptionally large order.

It has been discovered that the use of logical operators such as **&&** and **||** do not work with the BigInteger class when writing an if-statement as demonstrated in the code below.

Comments have been removed from the code for ease of reading on this page.

Your contributions are much appreciated.

```
public ArrayList<BigInteger> squareFree () {
    index = 0;
    fibValues_noSqr = fibValues;
    ArrayList<BigInteger> squares = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();

    int sqrScan;

    for (index = 0; index < fibValues_noSqr.size(); index++) {
        squares.add(BigInteger.valueOf(powerOf(index + 2, 2)));
    }

    for (index = 0; index < fibValues_noSqr.size(); index++) {
        for (sqrScan = 0; sqrScan < fibValues_noSqr.size(); sqrScan++) {
            if (squares.get(index).compareTo(fibValues_noSqr.get(sqrScan)) < 0 || squares.get(index).equals(fibValues_noSqr.get(sqrScan)) && fibValues_noSqr.get(sqrScan).remainder(squares.get(index))) {

                fibValues_noSqr.remove(sqrScan);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## The following error is revealed by Java in this scenario

The operator && is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, BigInteger

Comment: It appears `fibValues_noSqr.get(sqrScan).remainder(squares.get(index))` returns a `BigInteger` instead of a boolean value

Comment: For really long if statements, you might find it of interest to split them in multiple lines, so you can see each statement.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @GBlodgett. Interestingly, the logical or operator given as || offers no error, while the and operator given as && does.

Comment: @TheCodepreneur Because the two values used with `||` produce boolean values

Comment: @GBlogett Of course. :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @GBlogett and @Compass for your responses.

## Here is the working code

```
public ArrayList<BigInteger> squareFree () {
    index = 0;
    fibValues_noSqr = fibValues;
    ArrayList<BigInteger> squares = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();

    int sqrScan;

    for (index = 0; index < fibValues_noSqr.size(); index++) {
        squares.add(BigInteger.valueOf(powerOf(index + 2, 2)));
    }

    for (index = 0; index < fibValues_noSqr.size(); index++) {
        for (sqrScan = 0; sqrScan < fibValues_noSqr.size(); sqrScan++) {
            if (squares.get(index).compareTo(fibValues_noSqr.get(sqrScan)) < 0
             && fibValues_noSqr.get(sqrScan).mod(squares.get(index)) == new BigInteger("0")) {

                fibValues_noSqr.remove(sqrScan);
            }
    }
```

## Updated if-statement

```
for (index = 0; index < fibValues_noSqr.size(); index++) {
    for (sqrScan = 0; sqrScan < fibValues_noSqr.size(); sqrScan++) {
        if (squares.get(index).compareTo(fibValues_noSqr.get(sqrScan)) < 0
         && fibValues_noSqr.get(sqrScan).mod(squares.get(index)).equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {

            fibValues_noSqr.remove(sqrScan);
}
```

Comment: No, this answer is incorrect because your condition will always return false.  Don't use `==` to compare two `BigInteger` objects.  `fibValues_noSqr.get(sqrScan).mod(squares.get(index)) == new BigInteger("0")` can never be true, because `new BigInteger("0")` will never be the same object as one that already exists.

Comment: @Dawood, you are both correct. I have changed == BigInteger("0") to .equals(BigInteger.ZERO) and the output is now more appropriate. See this answer for updates.

Comment: You should also remove the incorrect part of the answer.  No point in leaving it there.

Comment: Don't use == to compare the values of objects. Use the equals method.